# problems on index in matlab nd array

Tags: matlab

Here is a simplified example

```
x = reshape(1:2*4*3,2,4,3); % 3d array
i1 = [1 1 2]; % index in dim 1
i2 = [2 1 3]; % index in dim 2
```

I want to extract `x(i1(ii),i2(ii),:)`, namely `x(1,2,:); x(1,1,:); x(2,3,:)`, which is of size [3,3].

But `x(i1,i2,:)` gives a 3d array of size [3,3,3].

So I used a stupid loop

```
y = nan(length(i1),3);
for ii = 1 : 3
    y(ii,:) = squeeze(x(i1(ii),i2(ii),:));
end
```

which gives

> ```
>  3    11    19
>  1     9    17
>  6    14    22
> ```

I believe this must not be the fancy way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reshape `x` to a `[8 * 3]` matrix and convert subscripts to linear indexes:

```
x = reshape(x,[],3);
y = x(sub2ind([2 4],i1,i2),:)
```